# Combine 2 separate foreach loops

Tags: php, loops, foreach, scrape

so far ive managed to scrape 2 elements from an external site on to my test page: 
http://mt-cloud.co.uk/nhs/

(Please do a test search on the page to view results)

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.nhs.uk/service-search/GP/m410ux/Results/4/-2.35167407989502/53.4519462585449/4/0?distance=25');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$document = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML($output);
$document->encoding = 'utf-8';
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$pnames = $xpath->query("//th[@class='fctitle']");
$addresses = $xpath->query("//td[@class='fcdetails fc-first']");
```

I have 2 foreach loops:

```
foreach ($pnames as $pname) {
$result1 = $document->saveHTML($pname);
}


foreach ($addresses as $address) {
$result2 = $document->saveHTML($address);
}
```

$result1 = Name of a GP Practice
$result2 = Address of GP Practice

As you see on the test page my result 1 and 2 are seperated..how do i get the them so i have Practice name and Practice Address together?

**UPDATE** (@Tri)

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($pnames); $i++){
$name= $document->saveHTML($pnames[$i]);
$name=str_replace ('<a href="/Services/', '<a href="http://www.nhs.uk/Services/', $name);
$address = $document->saveHTML($addresses[$i]);

echo $name.'<br>'.$address;
}
```

Only returns one result rather than all

**Here is my full php code:** http://mt-cloud.co.uk/nhs/content/code

**Image of data i'm trying to scrape** http://mt-cloud.co.uk/nhs/content/results.png

Comment: What do you mean by saying _$result1 and $result2 are together_ ? How exactly do you want to merge them? And from what I can see, Your `foreach`s are useless, because you are overwriting the values in `$result1` and `$result2` variables and at the end of each loop, you only have the last element's value in these variables

Comment: The link is a 404 at my end. You should include a *small* sample of the input data in the question.

Comment: @EhsanT - When I say together i mean it displays GP Practice Name (result1) and then on the next line GP Practice Address (result2) then the loop contines on to the next one.

Comment: @Nisse Engström I will add a test page shortly to show you what It displays so far.

Comment: Ive updated my question with a test page so you can see what I have done so far.

Comment: The code you are sharing with us is not enough to help you and actually I asked you a question you did not answer. You have a loop `foreach ($pnames as $pname)`, then you are assigning a value `$document->saveHTML($pname);` to a variable `$result1` in it. So in the first loop of this loop lets say the value is "Michael", you store "Michael" in `$result1`, Then for the second records the name is "John", you overwrite "John" to the variable `$result1`. So no matter how many records you have, you will always have one name and one address.

Comment: If you want us to be able to help you, please share more code. From what I can see, I think you can easily sort it out with an `array`. But it's only a guess without seeing your code...

Comment: here is my code: http://mt-cloud.co.uk/nhs/content/code

Comment: `$pnames` is an object, you can not treat it like an array. I'll post an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first code was OK, you just need to store your names and addresses in an 2 dimensional array and then loop through your array.

This part of the code is exactly same as yours:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.nhs.uk/service-search/GP/m410ux/Results/4/-2.35167407989502/53.4519462585449/4/0?distance=25');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$document = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML($output);
$document->encoding = 'utf-8';
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$pnames = $xpath->query("//th[@class='fctitle']");
$addresses = $xpath->query("//td[@class='fcdetails fc-first']");
```

Now we will create an array:

```
$results = array();
```

Then use your loops and store names and addresses as pairs in same indexs of array:

```
$iCnt = 0;
foreach ($pnames as $pname){
    $results[$iCnt]['name'] = $document->saveHTML($pname);
    $iCnt++;
}

$iCnt = 0;
foreach ($addresses as $address){
    $results[$iCnt]['address'] = $document->saveHTML($address);
    $iCnt++;
}
```

Now we have an array with pairs of names and addresses and if we loop through it, we can see them together:

```
for($iCnt = 0, $cnt = count($results); $iCnt < $cnt; $iCnt++){
    echo 'Name: '.$results[$iCnt]['name'].'<br>';
    echo 'Address: '.$results[$iCnt]['address'].'<br>';
}
```

That's all. The complete code will look like this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.nhs.uk/service-search/GP/m410ux/Results/4/-2.35167407989502/53.4519462585449/4/0?distance=25');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$document = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML($output);
$document->encoding = 'utf-8';
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$pnames = $xpath->query("//th[@class='fctitle']");
$addresses = $xpath->query("//td[@class='fcdetails fc-first']");

$results = array();

$iCnt = 0;
foreach ($pnames as $pname){
    $results[$iCnt]['name'] = $document->saveHTML($pname);
    $iCnt++;
}

$iCnt = 0;
foreach ($addresses as $address){
    $results[$iCnt]['address'] = $document->saveHTML($address);
    $iCnt++;
}

for($iCnt = 0, $cnt = count($results); $iCnt < $cnt; $iCnt++){
    echo 'Name: '.$results[$iCnt]['name'].'<br>';
    echo 'Address: '.$results[$iCnt]['address'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So just do not use foreach:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($pnames); $i++){
    $name= $document->saveHTML($pnames[$i]);
   $address = $document->saveHTML($addresses[$i]);
   //do something with your result
}
```

Note: you must make sure that length of addresses equal to pnames

Comment: It worked BUT! it is only displaying one result rather than all practices. 


for($i = 0; $i < count($pnames); $i++){
    $name= $document->saveHTML($pnames[$i]);
    $name=str_replace ('<a href="/Services/', '<a href="http://www.nhs.uk/Services/', $name);
    $address = $document->saveHTML($addresses[$i]);

echo $name.'<br>'.$address;
}

Comment: @itguyme Can you debug your code and show value of $pnames and $addresses? I tested my code with 2 simple arrays and it worked.

Comment: here is my fullcode: http://mt-cloud.co.uk/nhs/content/code

Comment: I can't run your code so I can't do anything with your code. You need to debug and give me the values of 2 arrays $pnames and $addresses.

Comment: as i'm bad at explaining i thought i would provide you with a image that shows you what data i'm scraping and want to output: http://mt-cloud.co.uk/nhs/content/results.png